# The keyword "use" in PHP gives a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING"

Tags: php, proxy

I want to use this [php proxy](https://github.com/jenssegers/php-proxy) script. I downloaded the zip, extracted the content and uploaded it to the server. I created a new index.php file and copied the code from the lib's example into it.

(Note: I am on PHP version 5.2.17-nmm2)

The lib requires Symphony so I uploaded that as well into the same directory. When I run the script, I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in index.php on line 3

```
<?php

use Proxy\Factory;
use Proxy\Response\Filter\RemoveEncodingFilter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Create the proxy factory.
$proxy = Factory::create();

// Add a response filter that removes the encoding headers.
$proxy->addResponseFilter(new RemoveEncodingFilter());

// Create a Symfony request based on the current browser request.
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// Forward the request and get the response.
$response = $proxy->forward($request)->to('http://example.com');

// Output response to the browser.
$response->send();

?>
```

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Comment: @JohnConde `phpinfo()` tells me that I am on `5.2.17-nmm2`

Comment: Oh lord, 5.2 ?! Lived behind a rock for 2 years: http://php.net/supported-versions.php :)?

Comment: Then it's not gonna work. `use` was introduced with PHP 5.3, which is also outdated already. Find a new shared hosting provider. You're paying for a service (professionally managed server setup) that you don't actually get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 5.2 does not support namespaces. You need to upgrade to at least PHP 5.3 although 5.6 is recommend as the rest are all obsolete. If you are on a shared host you should consider finding a new host. (Your version of php has not received security patches in a long time and should be considered vulnerable to attack).

Comment: Seems like I can switch to 5.6 by creating a `.htaccess` file in the same directory and add this content: `AddHandler php56-cgi .php`. I don't know why 5.2 is default, but well, it works now. Thanks for the help! :)